# Unique cell vectors

Tags: matlab, cell

I try to find unique arrays in a cell array. Suppose I have 6 cells with the following vectors:

```
a{1}=[1 2];
a{2}=[1 2 3];
a{3}=[2 3 4];
a{4}=[1 2];
a{5}=[1 2 3];
a{6}=[2 3 4];
```

Then the result should be `[1 2]`, `[1 2 3]` and `[2 3 4]`. I used `u=(cellfun(@unique,a,'Un',0))`, but it doesn't work, How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here a solution :

```
u = unique(cellfun(@num2str,a,'Un',0));
```

To transform them back to vector :

```
u2 = cellfun(@str2num,u,'Un',0);
```

Comment: By the way, there turned out existing two type data like '14  17  18  19  24',  [1x22 char], how to uniform them, and how to transfer them into numeric type？

Comment: @Yevis, you are right, you could send transform them back using the `str2num` function.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a way to stay numeric (without converting to strings):

```
ne = cellfun(@numel,a);
C = accumarray(ne(:),1:numel(a),[],@(x) {unique(vertcat(a{x}),'rows')});
C = C(~cellfun(@isempty,C));

C{1}
ans =
     1     2

C{2}
ans =
     1     2     3
     2     3     4
```

Each cell in `a` needs to contain a row vector.

Reorganize the output if needed:

```
m2c = @(x) mat2cell(x,ones(size(x,1),1),size(x,2));
C2 = cellfun(m2c,C,'uni',0);
C2 = vertcat(C2{:})

C2{1}
ans =
     1     2

C2{2}
ans =
     1     2     3

C2{3}
ans =
     2     3     4
```

Answer (score 0):

Another solution which doesn't involve converting to strings:

```
n = numel(a);
[i1 i2] = ndgrid(1:n); %// generate all pairs of elements (their indices, really)
equals = arrayfun(@(k) isequal(a{i1(k)},a{i2(k)}), 1:n^2); %// are they equal?
equals = tril(reshape(equals,n,n),-1); %// make non-symmetrical and non-reflexive
u = a(~any(equals)); %// if two elements are equal, remove one of them
```