# Given a cell array of vectors, delete vectors that are subsets of any other vector

Tags: matlab, cell

I wanna delete all the subsets of cell c, suppose I have 6 cell vectors: c{1}=[1 2 3]; c{2}=[2 3 4];
c{3}=[1 2 3 4 5 6]; c{4}=[2 3 4 7]; c{5}=[2 3 7]; c{6}=[4 5 6]; then I wanna delete [1 2 3], [2 3 4] and [4 5 6]. I used two for loops to find all these subsets, but it's too slow for large datasets, is there any simple way can do this?

Comment: Can you specify the criterion on which to base deletion? Does it depend on position, or on cell contents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code removes a vector if it's a subset of any other vector. The approach is very similar to [my answer to this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21917324/2586922):

```
n = numel(c);
[i1 i2] = meshgrid(1:n); %// generate all pairs of cells (their indices, really)
issubset = arrayfun(@(k) all(ismember(c{i1(k)},c{i2(k)})), 1:n^2); %// subset?
issubset = reshape(issubset,n,n) - eye(n); %// remove diagonal
c = c(~any(issubset)); %// remove subsets
```

Note that, in your example, `[2 3 7]` should also be removed.

Comment: The point is I don't know those subsets, I need find them first,and delete them.

Comment: If you don't know which subsets you want to delete, how do you find them or delete them?

Comment: Maybe I don't explain clearly, I have some cell vectors, and some of them are subsets of other cell vectors, I wanna find them first, and then delete them.

Comment: @Yevis Now that you have asked 6 questions on cell arrays, did you atempt to write a vectorized code?

Answer (score 0):

You could find the cells that are exact matches for a particular input vector s1 using the following approach:

```
indx = find(cell2mat(cellfun(@(x)strcmp(num2str(x),num2str(s1)),c,'un', 0)));
```

You can then loop over matches (which should now be a much smaller set), and remove them by setting their contents to an empty set:

```
for ii=1:length(indx)
    c{:,ii} = [];
end
```

Comment: The point is I don't know s1, I need to find them and delete them, any idea?

Comment: How do you determine which sets need to be removed?